# Beanstalk crashes after adding security group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I followed this guide http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.RDS.html to add an external RDS instance to my beanstalk environment.

But my environment crashes (meaning it times out during deploy) after I try to add the security group. Which is a security group called "default" referenced on my RDS Details page.

I added the security code via console and config, with the same result:

```
 ERROR: Timed out while waiting for command to Complete. The timeout can be set using the --timeout option.
```

Heres my option for setting the group:

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration
    option_name: SecurityGroups
    value: default
```

Im not sure where to look, since i cant even request logs for my instance. I cant SSH into either, I am getting: ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

I do have a second instance running on ec2 (with the new security group), but it doesnt seem to be reachable in any way.

Hints?

Comment: I think that should be the security group's ID, not the name. The ID will start with `sg-`.

Comment: Nope, if I add the security ID I get a validation error while deploying. Not so if I use the name.